# Run mysql in terminal without argument giving socket error

Tags: mysql, debian

When I type in `mysql` into terminal I got the following error:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

But if run mysql with some arguments like below:

`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p`

It asked me the mysql password that is already defined in /etc/my.cnf . So I pasted the same password and I got connected to the database terminal like this:

```
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 4
Server version: 10.6.4-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

In my `/etc/my.cnf` I have the following content:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=127.0.0.1
port=3360
max_allowed_packet=64M
local-infile=0
innodb_file_per_table

[client]
user=root
password=MYSQLPASSWORDHERE
socket=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysql.sock
```

The question is, since I already have predefined root password, port and bind-address in `/etc/my.cnf`, why does it still show error about socket if I run `mysql` command without any arguments

My aim is to run `mysql` command in terminal without any argument and it will present me the mysql terminal

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem. I had install Debian `mailutils` package before like this:

```
apt install mailutils
```

and it will include the following package:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gsasl-common guile-2.2-libs libgc1 libgsasl7 libidn11 libmailutils7 libmariadb3 libntlm0
  mailutils-common mariadb-common mysql-common
```

I think this is due to conflict of mariadb installation, So when I remove this mailutils package from Debian I don't have that error anymore. So I can simply run mysql in terminal without socket error.